# Conversion to Barracuda/Compressed Rows Doesn't Free Disk Space

Tags: mysql, innodb

I'm currently converting large tables to the Barracuda file format.  We are using file_per_table.

I had one table that decreased from 4.3gb in size down to 1.8gb and we're very happy about this.

However, the disk space used by MySQL is not decreasing.  How can I actually reclaim this disk space on the hard drive?  All I'm seeing is the table size when I run this query decreasing:

```
SELECT table_name AS "Tables", 
round(((data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024 / 1024), 2) "Size in GB" 
FROM information_schema.TABLES 
WHERE table_schema = "database"
ORDER BY (data_length + index_length) DESC;
```

However, when I run `df -h`, I see that mysql is still taking up the same amount of space (these should be significant decreases).

Comment: Where you using `innodb_file_per_table` before the conversion? What exactly did you run for the conversion (what row format were you using before and after)? What files do you expect to become smaller (.ibd or ibdata1, etc.)?